# How to fix endless periods?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, text-processing

As an assignment we were supposed to simply copy the code from our C++ book by D.S. Malik. This one is called "Text Processing". I've copied it exactly and read over the book a few more times trying to figure out the issue.

It's supposed to take the infile and copy&paste the text in the infile and then count the letters and list how many times a letter appears within the text. It pastes the text; however, whatever the last character is in the text it simply repeats that character infinitely. For me it is the period at the end of the text that it simply repeats repeatedly.

I'll show the text for the input below just before the code I've written.

**infile text**

```
The first device known to carry out calculation was the abacus.
The abacus was invented in Asia but was used in ancient Babylon,
Chine, and throughout Europe until the late middle ages. The aba-
cus uses a system of sliding beads in a rack for addition and sub-
traction. In 1642, the French philosopher and mathematician Blaise
Pascal invented the calculating device called the Pascaline. It
had eight movable dials on wheels and could calculate sums up to
eight figures long. Both the abacus and Pascaline could perform
only addition and subtraction operations. Later in the 17th cen-
tury, Gottfried von Leibniz invented a device that was able to add,
subtract, multiply, and divide.
```

**What should be in the outfile**

```
Today we live in an era where information is processed almost at the
speed of light. Through computers, the technological revolution is
drastically changing the way we live and communicate with one
another. Terms such as "the Internet," which were unfamiliar just
a few years ago, are very common today. With the help of computers you
can send letters to, and receive letters from, loved ones within
seconds. You no longer need to send a re´sume´ by mail to apply for a
job; in many cases you can simply submit your job application via
the Internet. You can watch how stocks perform in real time, and
instantly buy and sell them. Students regularly "surf" the Internet
and use computers to design their classroom projects. They also use
powerful word-processing software to complete their term papers.
Many people maintain and balance their checkbooks on computers.

The number of lines = 15
A count = 53
B count = 7
C count = 30
D count = 19
E count = 81
F count = 11
G count = 10
H count = 29
I count = 41
J count = 4
K count = 3
L count = 31
M count = 26
N count = 50
O count = 59
P count = 21
Q count = 0
R count = 45
S count = 48
T count = 62
U count = 24
V count = 7
W count = 15
X count = 0
Y count = 20
Z count = 0
```

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void initialize(int& lc, int list[]);
void copyText(ifstream& intext, ofstream& outtext, char& ch, int list[]);
void characterCount(char ch, int list[]);
void writeTotal(ofstream& outtext, int lc, int list[]);

int main()
{
    //Step 1; Declare variables
int lineCount;
int letterCount[26];
char ch;
ifstream infile;
ofstream outfile;

infile.open("textin.txt");                              //Step 2

if (!infile)                                            //Step 3
{
    cout << "Cannot open the input file."
        << endl;
    return 1;
}

outfile.open("textout.out");                            //Step 4

initialize(lineCount, letterCount);                     //Step 5

infile.get(ch);                                         //Step 6

while (infile)                                          //Step 7
{
    copyText(infile, outfile, ch, letterCount);         //Step 7.1
    lineCount++;                                        //Step 7.2
    infile.get(ch);                                     //Step 7.3
}

writeTotal(outfile, lineCount, letterCount);            //Step 8

infile.close();                                         //Step 9
outfile.close();                                        //Step 9

return 0;
}

void initialize(int& lc, int list[])
{
lc = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
    list[j] = 0;
} //end initialize

void copyText(ifstream& intext, ofstream& outtext, char& ch, int list[])
{
while (ch != '\n')                  //process the entire line
{
    outtext << ch;                  //output the character

    characterCount(ch, list);       //call the function character count

    intext.get(ch);                 //read the next character
}
outtext << ch;                      //output the newline character
} //end copyText

void characterCount(char ch, int list[])
{
int index;

ch = toupper(ch);                                               //Step a

index = static_cast<int>(ch) - static_cast<int>('A');           //Step b

if (0 <= index && index < 26)                                   //Step c
    list[index]++;
}//end characterCount

void writeTotal(ofstream& outtext, int lc, int list[])
{
outtext << endl << endl;
outtext << "The number of lines = " << lc << endl;

for (int index = 0; index < 26; index++)
    outtext << static_cast<char>(index + static_cast<int>('A')) << " count = " << list[index] << endl;
} //end writeTotal
```

Comment: Please, check this in debugger. After debugging by eyes, I found the following weakness in `copyText()`: If your file doesn't end with `\n` there is no chance to bail out of the loop. (You can check it with a very short oneliner instead your original input text. In case, I overlooked something try a file which ends with `\n` vs. one which doesn't.) You should extend the `while (ch != '\n')` with an additional condition for the good state of `intext`. (Please, confirm my guess in your debugger.) ;-)

Comment: Btw. did you notice that your output does contain a different text than the input? Is this a trick of the teacher to test your attention or just a copy&paste error made by you?

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your input I totally forgot I posted here! My code is actually completely correct it just turns out my input file that contained the text was incorrect. My professor sent me what the input text file was supposed to look like with the only difference being a indentation at the beginning of the input file and it fixed the error and runs fine each time now! Thanks for the assist though!